# Match regex i url

Tags: php, regex, pagination

I am trying to strip out a page query, in the middle of building pagination on a page.

The url is

```
$url = www.example.com?category=computers&page=10
```

Regex

```
$cleanUrl = preg_replace('/page=[0-9,]+&/', '', $url);
```

This isn't finding a match though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is failing because you are searching for an ampersand after the `page` parameter with its value.

You can make the ampersand optional by appending a question mark after it.

```
$url = 'www.example.com?category=computers&page=10';
$cleanUrl = preg_replace('/page=[0-9,]+&?/', '', $url);
```

Example, https://regex101.com/r/uW8uV8/1

For a more through regex try out:

```
<?php
$url = 'www.example.com?&category=cat&page=10';
$cleanUrl = rtrim(preg_replace('/(&|\?)page=[0-9,]+&?/', '$1', $url), '&?');
echo $cleanUrl;
```

This requires the `rtrim` function though to remove the trailing parameter glue. This will account for...

> Page by itself, www.example.com?page=10
>   Page as the last parameter, www.example.com?species=wolf&page=10
>   Page as the first parameter, www.example.com?page=10&species=wolf
>   Page as a middle parameter, www.example.com?cat=tom&mouse=jerry&page=10&species=wolf

Comment: it might be good if the beginning of the expression was matching against either ? or & so that something like `category=weirdpage=1000&` in the url doesn't get screwed up in their url. It's unlikely, but might be good to guard

Answer (score 0):

You should start and end your pattern with ~. This will work:

```
preg_replace('~&page=[0-9]+~', '', 'www.example.com?category=computers&page=10');
```

Comment: Why `*`? It looks, to me at least, like the OP is requiring a number or comma be present after `page=`. Also why `~` over `/`? It's just a delimiter.

Comment: Of course not * rather + because there will be one or more digits. As delimiter ~ and / will work.